# Desktop Launcher Execute Bash Script In Terminal from URL

Tags: command-line, unity, bash, scripts, launcher

My setup is I have a website (www.example.com) that I have uploaded bash scripts to www.example.com/location/of/bash/script.txt

I now would like a [Desktop Launcher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4SuV.png) (.desktop) file that I can use to open the terminal, then proceed to run the script from the website. So far I have created a .desktop file that can open the terminal but not successfully run the script from the URL.

My command within the .desktop file is

> gnome-terminal --execute bash -c "http:www.example.com/location/of/bash/script.txt" ; bash

When I click the .desktop file it opens, tries to run the script and gives the error 'no such file or directory'
any help on this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Also simple and dangerous:

Make your desktop file look like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Sample Application Name
Comment=A sample application
Exec=sh -c 'curl -s http://www.example.com/path/to/script.sh | bash'
Icon=application.png
Terminal=true
```

This will spawn a sub-shell, run 'curl' to read out the file, and then pipe it into bash.

Comment: I've had issues with a pipe in Exec lines before. They seem to not like pipes. I've only been able to use a pipe in a sub-shell when using .desktop files.

Comment: You're right, I tested and it doesn't work that way. Probably `Exec=` is just meant to run a single command.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you put together a script that does everything in 2 steps: download the original script , and then execute it locally.

Something like this :

```
#!/bin/bash

#download , save as /tmp/script
wget -O /tmp/script.sh www.example.com/location/of/bash/script.txt
#give executable permissions
chmod +x /tmp/script.sh
# run it
gnome-terminal --execute bash -c "/tmp/script.sh; bash"
```

Comment: The way you suggested above is a good solution, but I am looking for a one-file solution, almost like an installation wizard. For example, if I have a hello.sh that reads:  echo 'Hello', and then have hello.sh located on the internet, is there a way I can have a single separate file named 'runhello' that one can download and then run locally to execute the hello.sh script via bash locally? So that one can execute the script without having to know anything about executing items in the terminal.

Comment: I think you did that intentionally, but this leaves a interactive shell running on top of the script.

Comment: @kos I guess I could use `exec` there to get around that shell

Comment: No I just thought that maybe it's more convenient to let the terminal close, otherwise you have to shut it down manually, but well maybe OP likes it more that way. :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple and **dangerous**. Dangerous? Yes, see below …

```
wget -q -O - http://www.example.com/location/of/bash/runhello | bash
```

or with

```
bash <(curl -s http://www.example.com/location/of/bash/runhello)
```

or another combination of `wget`/`curl` and `bash`.

---

## Warning:

#### Perhaps it's a nice idea for your own scripts, but not for other people's:

#### Check the content of the script **before** executing and **never** run a script in the way `bash <(curl -s URL)` or `wget -q -O - URL | bash`.